# Exception in SOAP Web Service Parser already consumed

Tags: java, web-services, exception, soap

while executing soap web service . i got exception in 
org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.messagecontext (context)

can any one knows what is exact use of this method
i also got an exception

java.lang.UnsupportedOperationException: The parser is already consumed!

WFLogger.printOut("Inside Webservice 1 :: "+request.getBill_Amount());

```
WFLogger.printOut("Inside Webservice 1.1 :: "+request.getTotal_Net_Amount());
WFLogger.printOut("Inside Webservice 1.2 :: "+request.getPO_No());
WFLogger.printOut("Inside Webservice 1.3 :: "+request.getBilling_Currency());
WFLogger.printOut("Inside Webservice 1.3 :: "+request.getBusinessUnit());

LTTSWiCreateResponse responseToFCPG = null;
WMWorkitem workItem = null;
```

AttachFile fileAttachObject = new AttachFile();
    try {

```
    WFLogger.printOut("Inside Webservice 2 :: ");
    org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext localMessageContext = org.apache.axis2.context.MessageContext.getCurrentMessageContext();

    WFLogger.printOut("Inside Webservice 3 :: "+localMessageContext);
    SOAPBody localSOAPBody = localMessageContext.getEnvelope().getBody();

    WFLogger.printOut("Inside Webservice 4 :: "+localSOAPBody);
    org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.MessageContext localMessageContext1 = new org.apache.axis2.jaxws.core.MessageContext(localMessageContext);

    WFLogger.printOut("Inside Webservice 5 :: "+localMessageContext1);
    SOAPMessage localSOAPMessage = localMessageContext1.getMessage().getAsSOAPMessage();



    WFLogger.printOut("Inside Webservice 6 :: "+localSOAPMessage);
    //WFLogger.printOut("Inside getAttachmentIDs  :: "+localMessageContext1.getMessage().getAttachmentIDs());
```